# EF complex 'where query' with multiple fields and multiple values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
public async Task<ResponseDTO> UpdateCarModels(List<CarModelDTO> carModels)
{
     using (var dbContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())    
     {
        var carModelsDB = dbContext.carModels;    
        var filteredCarModelsDB = carModelsDB
            .Where(modelDB => carModels.Any(v => v.ModelNumber == modelDB.ModelNumber && v.ModelYear == modelDB.ModelYear));
     }
}
```

But the EF complains with

> The LINQ expression
> 'redacted comment'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable','AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Can any LINQ expert advice?

P.S I am trying to avoid loops

Comment: Please give details on `carModelsDB` and `carModels`. Also use a tag that matches your EF version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default EF Core can't translate that. You can create your own filter expression either by manipulating [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) manually or by using 3rd party library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) with `PredicateBuilder`. Something along these lines:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<CarModel>();
foreach (var v in carModels)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(modelDB => v.ModelNumber == modelDB.ModelNumber && v.ModelYear == modelDB.ModelYear);
}
var filteredCarModelsDB = carModelsDB.Where(predicate);
```